# AVX2 equivalent of std::clamp

Tags: stl, simd, avx2, clamp

Given a precision `p` between 1 and 16, I would like to clamp an AVX2 integer register between `-p/2` and `p/2`. I currently do this with `std::clamp` on non-AVX2 integers.

Is there a way of doing this with AVX2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implement saturating clamp the standard way with `x = min(max(x, lower_limit), upper_limit)`, using whatever width of integer you want.  Or let a compiler auto-vectorize `std::clamp` for you.

8, 16, or 32 are convenient; AVX2 doesn't have packed min/max for 64-bit integers but you could emulate it with `vpcmpgtq`.  AVX512 has `vpmaxsq`.  With just SSE2, only a couple size / signedness combinations of min/max operations were available.  SSE4.1 fixed that, so AVX2 has all 3 sizes in both signed and unsigned.

For example, for 8-bit integers, [`_mm256_max_epi8`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmaxsb:pmaxsw:pmaxsd:pmaxsq) for signed-integer max on `__m256i` vectors.

See [Intel's intrinsics guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/) to find intrinscs.