# Saturate 16-bit signed integer to 12-bits signed

Tags: optimization, signal-processing, simd, saturation-arithmetic

I'm working with an SDR that has a 12-bit signed ADC/DAC that stores in 16-bit IQ samples. I want to ensure that after all the DSP is done the samples saturate at 12 bits instead of getting truncated by the SDR.

This is the equivalent c++ code:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < block_size_with_header; i++) {
            if (floatSamples[i].real() > 2047)
                floatSamples[i].real(2047);
            if (floatSamples[i].imag() > 2047)
                floatSamples[i].imag(2047);
            if (floatSamples[i].real() < -2048)
                floatSamples[i].real(-2048);
            if (floatSamples[i].imag() < -2048)
                floatSamples[i].imag(-2048);
        }
```

Is there a faster way to do this using SIMD or Assembly? I've seen questions on here saturating at 16 bits or 8 bits, but not 12.

Thanks.

Comment: Assembly for what ISA?  Some have SIMD support, although usually only for add/sub and maybe multiply, not for left shifts.  (If you had efficient Rust `i16.saturating_mul(1<<4)`, you could do that and then arithmetic right shift by 4. https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i16.html#method.saturating_mul).  But x86 SSE has saturating multiply only for widening and adding horizontal pairs, not to the same width as the inputs.  ARM might well have something.  4x saturating add `vec += vec` operations could do a saturating left-shift by 4, but it might be more efficient to compare and blend.

Comment: Meant to say, some ISAs have *saturation* support with special instructions.  But the available operations differ by ISA.

Comment: Can you scale your previous operations by 16 (and already saturate them)? Otherwise. I guess a `pminsw` and `pmaxsw` is most efficient on x86 https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pminsb:pminsw

Comment: This is actually simple enough that at least clang is able to auto-vectorize this `arr[i] = std::min(2047, std::max(+arr[i], -2048));`: https://godbolt.org/z/ofb1dqcaW (gcc has problems, even with `std::min<int16_t>`).

Comment: Oh right, duh, `pmaxsw` / `pminsw`, it's just a clamping operation.  I was way overcomplicating this!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AVX2 equivalent of std::clamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63696946/avx2-equivalent-of-stdclamp) (there might be better duplicates, especially if you don't compile for AVX2)

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback. I'm on x86 Xeon using gcc. I'll look at the min/max solutions  and at the AVX2 post.

Comment: I'm not great with intrinsics, but if I understand correctly I do a pmaxsw against an array of the minimum value (anything lower is clamped), and a pminsw against an array of the max value (anything higher is clamped) and iterate over the data array in 512, 256, or 128 byte chunks of packed 16-bit integers, using the flag array on the last one to exclude any garbage. Did I get that right?

Do the arrays have to be mem_aligned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One interesting property of clamping, applying it twice doesn’t change the output, i.e. `clamp( clamp( x ) ) == clamp( x )` for all `x`. This greatly simplifies handling of remainder. Here’s AVX2 example, untested.

```cpp
#include <stdint.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

// Clamp 16 int16_t numbers in memory to the specified min/max values
inline void clamp16( int16_t* ptr, __m256i min, __m256i max )
{
    __m256i v = _mm256_loadu_si256( ( const __m256i* )ptr );
    v = _mm256_min_epi16( v, max );
    v = _mm256_max_epi16( v, min );
    _mm256_storeu_si256( ( __m256i* )ptr, v );
}

void saturate12bits_avx2( int16_t* ptr, size_t length )
{
    if( length >= 16 )
    {
        const __m256i max = _mm256_set1_epi16( 2047 );
        const __m256i min = _mm256_set1_epi16( -2048 );

        // We want a remainder of length [ 1 .. 16 ],
        // saves a branch testing for no remainder
        int16_t* const last = ptr + length - 16;
        for( ; ptr < last; ptr += 16 )
            clamp16( ptr, min, max );
        clamp16( last, min, max );
    }
    else
    {
        // Very small input, can't load AVX vectors
        int16_t* const end = ptr + length;
        for( ; ptr < end; ptr++ )
        {
            int16_t i = *ptr;
            i = std::min( i, (int16_t)2047 );
            i = std::max( i, (int16_t)-2048 );
            *ptr = i;
        }
    }
}
```

The input pointer doesn’t need to be aligned. Still, when it is aligned by 32 bytes, the function will run slightly faster.

Comment: Thank you.  This is very helpful.  I don't have my cheat-sheet in front of me, but isn't there a variation that has a flag vector for running the simd instruction on the last partial vector or vectors smaller than 256 bytes?

Comment: @JosephFreivald Instructions to conditionally load/store bytes or int16 numbers only arrived in AVX-512. AVX1 and AVX2 only have instructions to conditionally load/store 4-8 bytes elements: _mm256_maskload_epi32, _mm256_maskstore_pd, etc.
And this method with one last unaligned load/store is way simpler. The main issue, sometimes processing elements twice screws up the results, but luckily for clumping numbers it’s a safe thing to do.

Comment: @JosephFreivald: This is a good strategy that doesn't require messing with masks, although it does create a store-forwarding stall if the `last` vector partially overlaps the final store from the loop.  Ideally you'd load `last` before storing the final full vector, so the overlapping loads both happen before the overlapping stores.

Comment: One way to do that is rotating the loop (like for software-pipelining) so it loads for the next iteration happen at the bottom, so you leave the loop with a vector loaded but not stored.  (Peel the load needed by the first iteration to set up for entering the loop, and put the final store after load + clamp of the unaligned final vector outside the loop).  If you did have AVX-512BW, AArch64 SVE, or I think RISC-V extension V, then masking could be an alternate strategy for handling the end, which would also work for short inputs.

Comment: Another way to avoid a store-forwarding stall would be to load `__m256i lastvec` before the first iteration, but that would probably stall on a cache miss, or worse a TLB miss that delays TLB miss handling for the start of the loop.  And the cache line might get evicted again during the loop so the store would still miss.  It would be fine for small arrays that tend to be hot in L1d or L2 cache.